# React - Error : TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi i am new to react js and i have this problem on my login page,  `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')`
*the problem comes from the function handleSubmit() specialy from .then(user => {)}*
can you help me please

> **PS : im using firebase**

```
   import React, {useState, useEffect, useContext} from 'react'
   import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
   import {FirebaseContext} from '../Firebase'
   const Login = (props) => {

   const firebase = useContext(FirebaseContext);

   const [email, setEmail] = useState('');

   const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

   const [btn, setBtn] = useState(false);

   const [error, setError] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
    if(password.length > 5 && email !==""){
        setBtn(true)
    }else if(btn){
        setBtn(false)
    }
}, [password, email, btn])

const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    firebase.loginUser(email, password)
    .then((user) => {
        setEmail('');
        setPassword('');
        props.history.push('/welcome');
    })
    .catch(error => {
        setError(error);
        setEmail('');
        setPassword('');
    })
}

return(myhtml)
export default Login;
```

Comment: You'll need to show us the `FirebaseContext` in order to help you solve the problem. For now all we can say for sure is that `firebase.loginUser` does not return a promise, and does not seem to return anything at all actually.

Comment: i was using a bad password ;-; this is why its wasn't a probleme in my code, thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1):

the server must have responded with null.

try

```
firebase.loginUser(email, password)
.then((user) => {
    if(!user) return;
    setEmail('');
    setPassword('');
    props.history.push('/welcome');
})
.catch(error => {
    setError(error);
    setEmail('');
    setPassword('');
})
```

if you are rendering a state on the screen you should check that the value is not null

example

```
{email ? email : 'does not exist'}
```

Comment: The error is about `.then` of undefined. The error has triggered *before* it enters the callback. This will not help.

Answer (score 1):

`firebase.loginUser(email, password)` returns `undefined`. You try to access the `then` property of an undefined object.